# Changing Linux desktop's environment variables without re-login

Tags: linux, environment-variables, cinnamon, desktop-environments

I'm setting a particular environment variable in my `.bashrc`, and, once I source it, it is available both in the shell itself and in gVim instances that I start from the shell. But, if I start a gVim instance through the system GUI menu, that instance doesn't see that variable.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22267192/8127), gVim inherits the desktop environment's variables. In that case, is there a way to dynamically change values in that environment or to add new environment variables to it? I understand that setting the variable in `.profile` will make it available to the desktop environment when it is restarted, but is there a way to make the change without a restart or a relogin?

Answer (score 1):

Each process inherits a *copy* of the environment variables. So, generally, no – you should restart the entire desktop session from scratch.

It might be enough to restart just the "system menu", in case it is a separate program – e.g. in Xfce4, you could kill `xfce4-panel` and start it again from the 'fixed' shell, and it will have inheritted the updated environment from your shell.

Note that most environment variables should be set from **`~/.profile`** instead, as not all desktop sessions are started via bash, and even then are rarely told to read `~/.bashrc`.

---

As an exception, some programs have functions to update their environment from outside, because restarting them would affect too many things – such as `tmux`, `dbus-daemon`, or `systemd --user`. But even they cannot push the new environment into already running services.